# Checking if text file is empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub btnCreateAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click

        Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(strUsersPath)
        Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strUsersPath)
            Dim line As String
            line = r.ReadLine ' nothing happens after this point
            Do While (Not line Is Nothing)

                If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
                    MsgBox("File is empty, creating master account")
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    MsgBox("Creating normal account")
                End If
                line = r.ReadLine

            Loop
        End Using

End Sub
```

I am having some problems. Basicaly I have a streamreader opening up a .txt file where the directory is stored in 'strUsersPath'. I am trying to get the code so that if the file is empty, it does one thing, and if the file is not empty (there is a user) then it does another.

If I have a user in my txt file, the code gives the msgbox("creating normal account"), as expected, however when I do not have a user, it does not give me the other msgbox, and I can't seem to work out why. I suspect it is because IsNullOrWhiteSpace is not the right thing to use for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

***EDIT***
This is the code I have also tried, same result, clicking the button does nothing if there is already a user.

```
Private Sub btnCreateAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click

        Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(strUsersPath)
       Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Index.strUsersPath)
            Dim line As String
            line = r.ReadLine ' nothing happens after this point
            Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                fi.Refresh()
                If Not fi.Length.ToString() = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("File is empty, creating master account") ' does not work
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    MsgBox("Creating normal account") ' works as expected
                End If
                line = r.ReadLine

            Loop
        End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Check if your application can open that file

Comment: You can check if file is empty with `FileInfo`'s `Length` property without opening it.

Comment: @BartoszKP I forgot to mention, I tried that and that didn't seem to work either!

Comment: @SamCousins: If that didn't work, try [`fileInfo.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) before you chek `fileInfo.Length`.

Comment: Have you verified `strUsersPath` variable contents in the second case? Are you sure the file in that path exists and is empty? Perhaps verify the `Exists` property.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please see my updated OP.

Comment: @SamCousins: Why do you the streamreader at all if you have created the `FileInfo` object and checked it's `Length`  property in the ext line and it returns 0? Apart from that you should set `OPTION STRICT` to on because it prevents errors. `If Not fi.Length.ToString() = 0` would not compile because you are comparing strings and integers. Just check `If fi.Length = 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need a StreamReader for this. All you need is `File.ReadAllText`

```
If File.ReadAllText(strUsersPath).Length = 0 Then
    MsgBox("File is empty, creating master account")
Else
    MsgBox("Creating normal account")
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using this method

```
If New FileInfo(strUsersPath).Length.Equals(0) Then
    'File is empty.
Else
    'File is not empty.
End If
```